# C++ Replacing a character in an array without the use of C-String Library Functions

Tags: c++

I was given a set of questions, basically asking me to recreate the utility of certain library functions such as strlen() and strcpy() without using them.

However, one of the questions has gotten me stumped. It's a function that replaces a character in a string with anything you choose.

Example :

Str : marix xdyssey

target : x

replacement : o

Output : mario odyssey

This is what I have right now

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int replace(char *s2, char target, char replacementChar);

const int MAX_SIZE = 128;

int main()
{
    char str2[MAX_SIZE], target, replacement;
    int change;

    cout << "Enter your string : " << endl;
    cin.getline(str2, MAX_SIZE);
    cout << "What's your target?" << endl;
    cin >> target;
    cout << "What do you want to replace it with?" << endl;
    cin >> replacement;

    replace(str2, target, replacement);

}

int replace(char *s2, char target, char replacementChar)
{
    int change = 0;

    for(int i=0; s2[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        if(s2[i] == target)
        {
            swap(s2[i], replacementChar);
            change++;
        }
    }
    cout << "There were " << change << " change(s)." << endl;
    cout << s2;
    return change;
}
```

And even though "change" returned 2, I was given the output of "mario xdyssey".

Any advice or hints as to how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you use `swap`? What do you think is in `replacementChar` after the first time you swap?

Comment: Why are you using `swap()`? That changes `replacementChar` to the value that was previously in `s2[i]`.

Comment: YAIT (yet another incompetent teacher)

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
        swap(s2[i], replacementChar);
```

to:

```
        s2[i] = replacementChar;
```

`swap()` exchanges the values of the two variables, so after the first replacement, `replacementChar` contains the same thing as `target`, so nothing gets updated.

Comment: Ah, that's where I went wrong! I though I had tried that the first time around before using `swap()` so I didn't think of trying it again.

This worked out, thanks so much.